# Coq: Remove all (nested) parentheses from a sum

Tags: coq, associativity

Suppose I've a sum like `a + (b + (c + d))`, which I wish to transform into `a + b + c + d` to apply a lemma.

Doing this manually with `Nat.add_assoc` is extremly tedious. Is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 4):

The 'easy but not nice' way I would use is `replace (a + (b + (c + d)))) with (a + b + c + d) by now omega`

Comment: Why is it not nice?
Additionally, you can also do `by auto with *`.

Comment: If you ever looked at the output term created by `omega`, you'll understand. Most of the time it is overly complicated, and a small proof using rewrite will be way smaller. But that's a matter of personal opinion ;)

Comment: `by omega` would work as well; and `by ring` also solves the problem. The former needs `Omega` module to be imported; the latter -- `Arith`.

Comment: @Vinz why is the output term important? Is the problem of `omega` that it _might_ slow down the compilation/check stage?

Comment: Yep, that's the idea. In this particular case I don't think it will really matter. But in bigger development, this might change the execution time of a `Qed` significantly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `repeat` tactical, which repeats some tactic until it cannot be applied anymore:

```
repeat rewrite Nat.add_assoc.
```

or a more concise version:

```
rewrite !Nat.add_assoc.
```

It works just the same as the variant with `repeat`.

The downside of this approach is that it rewrites everywhere in the goal. So, you might want to select some part of your formula to do the rewrites on it only.